# How to vectorize function that concatenates values in duplicated rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that transforms table that looks like this:

| ID | Year | Period | Duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A9999 | 2020 | 23 | False |
| A9999 | 2019 | 22 | True |
| A9999 | 2018 | 20 | True |
| B0000 | 2019 | 24 | False |
| B0000 | 2018 | 12 | True |
| C5555 | 2019 | 18 | False |

to this:

| ID | Year | Period | Duplicate | Concat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A9999 | 2020 | 23 | False | 2018x2019x2020_23 |
| A9999 | 2019 | 22 | True | 2018x2019x2020_22 |
| A9999 | 2018 | 20 | True | 2018x2019x2020_20 |
| B0000 | 2019 | 24 | False | 2018x2019_24 |
| B0000 | 2018 | 12 | True | 2018x2019_12 |
| C5555 | 2019 | 18 | False | 2019_18 |

It concatenates values in `Year` column if the rows have the same `ID` value and joins it with `Period` value from current row.

The function is as follows:

```
def create_concat_col(df):
    concat_dic = {}

    for index, cur_row in df.iterrows():
        cur_id = cur_row['ID']
        cur_year = str(cur_row['Year'])

        if cur_id not in concat_dic:
            concat_dic[cur_id] = cur_year
        else:
            concat_dic[cur_id] = cur_year + 'x' + concat_dic[cur_id]

        if not cur_row['Duplicate']:
            concat_dic[cur_id] = concat_dic[cur_id] + '_' + str(cur_row['Period'])

    df.insert(12, 'Concat', '')
    df['Concat'] = df['ID'].map(concat_dic)

    return df
```

The function does its job but unfortunately is very slow since it iterates through all rows. Is there a way to vectorize this function so it's faster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with join values by `x` in swapped order and add `Period` converted to `string`:

```
df['Concat'] = (df.astype({'Year':str})
                  .groupby('ID')['Year']
                  .transform(lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1]))
                  .add('_' + df['Period'].astype(str)))
print (df)
      ID  Year  Period  Duplicate             Concat
0  A9999  2020      23      False  2018x2019x2020_23
1  A9999  2019      22       True  2018x2019x2020_22
2  A9999  2018      20       True  2018x2019x2020_20
3  B0000  2019      24      False       2018x2019_24
4  B0000  2018      12       True       2018x2019_12
5  C5555  2019      18      False            2019_18
```

If need first `Period`:

```
g = df.astype({'Year':str, 'Period': str}).groupby('ID')
f = lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1])
df['Concat'] = g['Year'].transform(f).add('_' + g['Period'].transform('first'))
print (df)
      ID  Year  Period  Duplicate             Concat
0  A9999  2020      23      False  2018x2019x2020_23
1  A9999  2019      22       True  2018x2019x2020_23
2  A9999  2018      20       True  2018x2019x2020_23
3  B0000  2019      24      False       2018x2019_24
4  B0000  2018      12       True       2018x2019_24
5  C5555  2019      18      False            2019_18
```

Comment: @jezrael I think your output is incorrect as the last number should be invariable per group (or OP's provided output is wrong)

Comment: @JanValušek can you check your output?

Comment: @mozway I am actually fine with each of the outputs. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `groupby` and `agg` to get the "Concat" column, then merge to get the output:

```
df2 = (df.astype({'Year': str, 'Period': str})
         .groupby('ID').agg({'Year': 'x'.join,
                             'Period': 'first'})
         .apply('_'.join, axis=1)
         .rename('Concat')
         .reset_index()
        )
df.merge(df2, on='ID')
```

output:

```
      ID  Year  Period  Duplicate             Concat
0  A9999  2020      23      False  2020x2019x2018_23
1  A9999  2019      22       True  2020x2019x2018_23
2  A9999  2018      20       True  2020x2019x2018_23
3  B0000  2019      24      False       2019x2018_24
4  B0000  2018      12       True       2019x2018_24
5  C5555  2019      18      False            2019_18
```